# Protected render_to_string error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, ruby-on-rails-2, pdfkit

I'm trying to export with `resque` using `PDFkit` some pages. But I got several errors when I try to do it with the `render_to_string`.

Errors:

```
protected method `render_to_string' called for #<ActionController::Base:0x5a65748 @real_format=nil>
```

when using this:

```
html = ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(
        :template => route,
        :locals => locals,
        :layout => layout
)
```

and this one:

```
undefined method `render_to_string' for Print:Module
```

when using this:

```
html = render_to_string(
        :template => route,
        :locals => locals,
        :layout => layout
)
```

The method I'm calling is "`return_generic_pdf_kit`" and lives in the `/lib/print.rb`, and I'm calling it from a resque worker like this:

```
kit = Print.return_generic_pdf_kit(url,
                             {
                                 :print_blank_eval => evaluator_type,
                                 :print_blank_prov => provider_type,
                                 :print_blank_appl => applicant_type,
                                 :form => form,
                                 :scholarship => scholarship
                             },
                             false, 1)
```

Hope someone can help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it

```
ac = ActionController::Base.new()
ac.render_to_string(:template => route,
        :locals => locals,
        :layout => layout)
```

Comment: the ac variable will receive the html? or should I do something like:

html = ac.render_to_string(:template => route,
        :locals => locals,
        :layout => layout)

Comment: ` html = ac.render_to_string(:template => route, :locals => locals, :layout => layout)` will work and result will be in `html` variable

Comment: This doesn't work for me - why would it? looks the same